# Graph Fourier transform: the adjoint notation for the eigenbasis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, signal-processing, eigenfunctions

> It is well-known that for a real symmetric matrix $L$ (here, graph
>   Laplacian) one can write the eigenvalue decomposition as
>
> $$ L = U \Lambda U^{\mathsf T}, $$ where $U$ is a *real eigenvector
>   matrix*. Moreover, in graph signal processing papers, including the
>   great paper by [Shuman et al.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6494675) (cf. page 4), the adjoint (complex
>   conjugate) of $U$ is used to define the graph Fourier transform
>   $\mathcal{F}_{G}$ as  $$ \hat{x} = \mathcal{F}_{G} x = U^{*}x, $$
>   where $x$ is the signal in vector form and $U^{*}$ is the complex
>   conjugate of $U$.

I am curious to know is there any specific reason for using the notation of *complex conjugate* since $U$ is real?